# Fourier transform without characters (Eigenfunctions of an operator)

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sp.spectral-theory, fourier-transform, quantum-mechanics

Let's consider a very simple problem in quantum mechanics:

We have, in $\mathbb R,$  a potential barrier of the form
$$
V(x) = V_0 \mathbf 1_{[-a,a]}(x),
$$
where $\mathbf 1_{[-a,a]}$ denotes the indicator function. A particle of energy $E$ is incident from the left, giving eigenfunctions of the form $e^{\pm ik x},$ where $k =\sqrt{2mE}/\hbar,$ or $e^{\pm Kx}$. Carefulling picec these together at the boundary of the barrier gives a family of eigenfunctions or the Schrodinger operator
$$
H=- \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2 }+ V(x).
$$

Solutions of the Schrodinger equation can be obtained by decomposing w.r.t. these functions. The mechanism is similar to Fourier transform.

However, there is one caveat: the eigenfunctions are not unitary characters of the additive group on $\mathbb R.$ So Fourier transform on locally compact Abelian group does not work.

**I know that this is where spectral theorem applies** - however the spectral theorem is not so precise - it just gives me the existence of unitary equivalence to a multiplication operator; it does not tell me the exact form of this equivalence.

**How can we prove rigorously that any solution of $H \psi = i\hbar \partial_t \psi$  is a "linear combination" of eigenfunctions above, in the form of an integral?** i.e. if $\psi_E$ is the eigenfunction corresponding to eigenvalue $E,$ then do we have some relations like
$$
\hat u(E) = \int \psi_E(x)^* u(x) dx, u(x) = \int \psi_E(-x)^* \hat u(E) dE? 
$$

Comment: What you're asking for seems to be closely related to the so-called *nuclear spectral theorem*. But I'm very hesitant to call this an "answer" to your question, since most versions of the nuclear spectral theorem that I've seen left me with the feeling that, while they back up the intuition that "things are similar as for the Fourier transform", they are a much less powerful tool when it comes to really proving something.

Comment: V. Marchenko, Sturm-Liouville operators and their applications, Birkhauser, 1986.